# RVM cannot load ruby gem -- no such file

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I've been developing a ruby gem and suddenly while trying to test it, it won't load. I get a no such file when trying to `require "xmlmc-rb"`

I've tried the following

```
rvm reinstall ruby-2.2.1
rvm use ruby-2.2.1

which ruby -- /Users/rich/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby
which gem -- /Users/rich/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/gem

gem list | grep xmlmc -- xmlmc-rb (2.0.3)
gemset list -- gemsets for ruby-2.2.1 (found in /Users/rich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1)
=> (default)
   global

ls ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems | grep xmlmc -- xmlmc-rb-2.0.3
```

I'm not sure what else to do. I've been developing this gem for a while, I took a break for a few months and come back to it like this.

Comment: Your title is misleading. RVM doesn't load anything. If "RVM" is in the title as a tag because you think it helps, don't do that. Tags don't go into the title, though it's OK if they're part of the natural flow of the sentence.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. I put RVM in the title so that people would know I'm using ruby version manager. I'll keep it to the tags in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it could have been a path error. Ran `rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles` and everything is working again. Strange but I'm just glad it's working.